# Querying the entire table VS Querying each partition of the table

Tags: sql, database-performance, database-partitioning, postgresql-11

Let's say I have a table with multiple partitions and I need to query something from the entire table. Is there a difference, from a performance point of view, between running a single sql query on the entire table and running one sql for each partition?

LE: I'm using Postgres

Comment: One of the goal of partitioning is to eliminate excessive search for data. SQL Server uses partition elimination based on partition function.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added the tag

Comment: What do you mean by "query each partition of the table"?  An example of the two query approaches would really help me understand what you actually mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Microsoft SQL Server when you create a `partition function` for partitioning a table, this function partitions data and route the query to the best data file.

For example if your partition function creates in a `datetime` field and partition data yearly, your query just run in a single data file that contains your where clause data.

Therefore you don't need to separate your query and the SQL Server Engine will do that automatically.

Comment: So the conclusion is that both "Querying the entire table" and "Querying each partition of the table" should have the same performance?

Comment: @AndreiRS Yeap ;)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your intention is.

If you already have a partitioned table and are deciding what the best strategy to retrieve all rows is, then running a query against the partitioned table is almost certainly the faster solution.

Retrieval of all partitions will most likely be parallelized (depending on your configuration of parallel query). If you query each partition manually, you would need to implement that yourself e.g. creating multiple connections with each one running a query against one partition.

---

However if your intention is to *decide* whether it makes sense to partition a table, then the answer isn't so straightforward. If you have to query all rows of the table very often, then this is usually (slightly) slower than querying a single non-partitioned table. If that is the exception and you almost always have run queries that target a single partition, then partitioning does make sense.